# Give palette elements border or title

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, color-picker

I have my jquery spectrum plugin: [Spectrum](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) with a palette of colors like these: [Palette](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/example/)

And I need to give the colorpicker a individual palette with colors.
There are 5 primary colors and about 15 other "secondary" colors, so I want to mark/highlight them as primary. For example to give them a black border around the boxes or to have a title for the 5 primary colors.

See this Fiddle as example(Full example): 
http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/ctkY3/

```
<a href='http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum'>&lt;--Spectrum Homepage</a>

<h2>Basic Usage</h2>
<input type='text' class="basic"/>
<em id='basic-log'></em>

<h2>Full Example</h2>
<input type='text' id="full"/>
```

JS

```
$(".basic").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change: function(color) {
        $("#basic-log").text("change called: " + color.toHexString());
    }
});

$("#full").spectrum({
    color: "#ECC",
    showInput: true,
    className: "full-spectrum",
    showInitial: true,
    showPalette: true,
    showSelectionPalette: true,
    maxSelectionSize: 10,
    preferredFormat: "hex",
    localStorageKey: "spectrum.demo",
    move: function (color) {

    },
    show: function () {

    },
    beforeShow: function () {

    },
    hide: function () {

    },
    change: function() {

    },
    palette: [
        ["rgb(0, 0, 0)", "rgb(67, 67, 67)", "rgb(102, 102, 102)",
        "rgb(204, 204, 204)", "rgb(217, 217, 217)","rgb(255, 255, 255)"],
        ["rgb(152, 0, 0)", "rgb(255, 0, 0)", "rgb(255, 153, 0)", "rgb(255, 255, 0)", "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
        "rgb(0, 255, 255)", "rgb(74, 134, 232)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)", "rgb(153, 0, 255)", "rgb(255, 0, 255)"], 
        ["rgb(230, 184, 175)", "rgb(244, 204, 204)", "rgb(252, 229, 205)", "rgb(255, 242, 204)", "rgb(217, 234, 211)", 
        "rgb(208, 224, 227)", "rgb(201, 218, 248)", "rgb(207, 226, 243)", "rgb(217, 210, 233)", "rgb(234, 209, 220)", 
        "rgb(221, 126, 107)", "rgb(234, 153, 153)", "rgb(249, 203, 156)", "rgb(255, 229, 153)", "rgb(182, 215, 168)", 
        "rgb(162, 196, 201)", "rgb(164, 194, 244)", "rgb(159, 197, 232)", "rgb(180, 167, 214)", "rgb(213, 166, 189)", 
        "rgb(204, 65, 37)", "rgb(224, 102, 102)", "rgb(246, 178, 107)", "rgb(255, 217, 102)", "rgb(147, 196, 125)", 
        "rgb(118, 165, 175)", "rgb(109, 158, 235)", "rgb(111, 168, 220)", "rgb(142, 124, 195)", "rgb(194, 123, 160)",
        "rgb(166, 28, 0)", "rgb(204, 0, 0)", "rgb(230, 145, 56)", "rgb(241, 194, 50)", "rgb(106, 168, 79)",
        "rgb(69, 129, 142)", "rgb(60, 120, 216)", "rgb(61, 133, 198)", "rgb(103, 78, 167)", "rgb(166, 77, 121)",
        "rgb(91, 15, 0)", "rgb(102, 0, 0)", "rgb(120, 63, 4)", "rgb(127, 96, 0)", "rgb(39, 78, 19)", 
        "rgb(12, 52, 61)", "rgb(28, 69, 135)", "rgb(7, 55, 99)", "rgb(32, 18, 77)", "rgb(76, 17, 48)"]
    ]
});
```

Comment: How do we know which 5 are your primary colors?

Comment: @Popnoodles It's not necessary to know which colors are primary.. I just need to know if it's possible to highlight any colors. But lets say the first row are all primary colors

Comment: It helps but ok it's possible.

Comment: @Popnoodles could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctkY3/4095/)

Each thumb has the color stored as data, and the plugin has a callback that runs on showing the palette. We can use those things.

Create a list of your primary colors

```
var primary = ["rgb(208, 224, 227)", "rgb(201, 218, 248)", "rgb(207, 226, 243)", "rgb(217, 210, 233)", "rgb(234, 209, 220)"];
```

Add the relevant CSS

```
.primary-thumb{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

In the show function of the pallete options, include code that will add the CSS class to thumbs that have those colors.

```
show: function () {
    $('.sp-thumb-el').each(function(){
        var this_color = $(this).data('color');
        if ($.inArray(this_color, primary) >= 0){
            $(this).find('.sp-thumb-inner').addClass('primary-thumb');
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: If i run this demo, I can't see any borders. Do I just overlook them, or where should they appear?

Comment: My mistake, I tried something with the CSS and didn't fix it. You may have spotted that background-color had the wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick hack.

```js
/*The Array of RGP colors you want to border*/
var arrayOfRGBColors = ['rgb(255, 128, 0)', 'rgb(255, 235, 205)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'];

/*Simple flat pallete*/
$("#flat").spectrum({
    flat: true,
    showPaletteOnly: true,
    showPalette: true,
    color: 'blanchedalmond',
    palette: [
        ['black', 'white', 'blanchedalmond',
            'rgb(255, 128, 0);', 'hsv 100 70 50'],
        ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'violet']
    ],
    move: function (color) {
        border();
    },
    show: function () {
        border();
    },
    beforeShow: function () {
        border();
    },
    hide: function () {
        border();
    },
    change: function () {
        border();
    },
});

function border() {
    /*Foreach pallete item, set the css*/
    $('.sp-thumb-inner').each(function () {
        /*Get the RGB color*/
        var color = $(this).css('background-color');
        /*If the color is found in the array*/
        if ($.inArray(color, arrayOfRGBColors) > 0) {
            /*Set the border*/
            $(this).addClass('bord');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.bord{
    border:1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.7.1/spectrum.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.7.1/spectrum.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type='text' id="flat" />
```